# Kmail2 really slow

Tags: kubuntu, kde, email, kmail

Ever since migrating to Kubuntu 11.10 and the forced migration to kmail2 with the akonadi backend I am having serious performance problems. Is there some sort of maintenance or cleanup task that I can run to optimize it.

I have large maildir based emails dating back to 2000 and would really like to keep having all around but worst case I might have to back it up and start fresh. Any tips to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"While overall, Kmail2 is actually quite good imo, the migration process is not."**

The Kubuntu Forums has: Topic: Upgrading to 11.10 and Kmail2 Migration Issues /1/.

**Links**

1. http://kubuntuforums.net/forums/index.php?topic=3118698.0